# Where can I find and install the dependencies for pygame?

Tags: python, linux, debian, pygame

I am relatively new to linux and am trying to install the pygame dev environment for python. When I run the setup.py it says that I need to install the following dependencies, one of which I found and installed (SDL). However, the others have been more elusive.

```
Hunting dependencies...
sh: smpeg-config: command not found
WARNING: "smpeg-config" failed!
SDL     : found 1.2.14
FONT    : not found
IMAGE   : not found
MIXER   : not found
SMPEG   : not found
PNG     : not found
JPEG    : not found
SCRAP   : found
PORTMIDI: not found
PORTTIME: not found
```

If you could give me some guidance I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done an `apt-get update` (not to be confused with `apt-get upgrade`)? When I'm running on anything other than Debian stable, I have to update my repositories regularly.

Comment: Hi Wilduck, I just learned about that recently and had done it earlier. I'm worried that my sources.list may not be up-to-date though. Currently it reads like this:
 ----------------deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian lenny main  
  *************deb http://security.debian.org lenny/updates main------- I added the * and - symbols to separate the sources

Comment: If you think your sources.list might be out of date, I would suggest heading over to superuser.com, they'll be able to help diagnose the issue a little better. Good luck.

Comment: You can refer to this compilation [section](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For debian, there is a pre-built package available. See [here](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/pygame.html). You should be able to install it with `apt-get` or something similar.

Comment: Hi Constantinius I downloaded the .deb from the linked site and get a host of dependencies not available. It looks like im missing libsmpeg and libsdl, which I thought I installed sdl already. I think I may be missing some links in my sources.list table and thats why I am missing a lot of packages normall available using apt-get

Answer (score 38):

`$ sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev   libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev`

Or sorted slightly:

```sh
sudo apt-get install \
  python-dev \
  python-numpy \
  subversion \
  ffmpeg \
  libsdl1.2-dev \
  libsdl-image1.2-dev \
  libsdl-mixer1.2-dev \
  libsdl-ttf2.0-dev \
  libavcodec-dev \
  libavformat-dev \
  libportmidi-dev \
  libsmpeg-dev \
  libswscale-dev \
```

Comment: Also works for pygame3 if you replace python-dev with python3-dev

Answer (score 26):

Behold, one of the most useful tools on debian-based dsitros:

```
apt-get build-dep python-pygame
```

Installs all the dependences required to build pygame :)

On Fedora:

```
yum-builddep package_name
```

Comment: This worked for me.  This is what I needed because I was installing `pygame` using `pip`.

Answer (score 3):

this steps work for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev   libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev

$ sudo pip3 install pygame
```

Answer (score 3):

My list for Arch Linux:

`sudo pacman -Sy sdl_ttf sdl_sound sdl_image sdl_mixer portmidi`

Comment: Thank you, I was having problems bfr

Comment: @MichaelEnitan: were these dependencies enough to get it working?

Comment: @danukar: Yes they were

Answer (score 2):

If you run one of supported Linux distributions ([see "Unix Distributions" section](http://pygame.org/download.shtml)), you just install pygame from a repository, and dependencies are installed, too.

Generally, you need SDL (libsdl and friends), Python, Numpy.

Comment: Pygame continues to be elusive, I will work on it a little more today. I'm having trouble finding what the source address would be to put into my sources.list in order to get pygame.

Answer (score 2):

I (debian buster, python2) recently tried to update pygame from 1.9.4 to 2.0.2, and it seems there has been a switch to newer dependencies compared to the other answers given here, for example from `libsdl1.2-dev` to `libsdl2-dev`.

This is what i needed to install for `pip2 install --upgrade pygame` to go through without error:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libportmidi-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu 20.04 as of this date I had the SDL missing error and found a solution only to run into a freetype error then had to reinstall because the --user option in the python3 pip command kept me from accessing the module

Here is a one line solution that worked for me with python version 3.8.2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev install libfreetype6-dev && python3 pip -m install -u pygame
```

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu 20.04, was enough with these packages: `libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev libportmidi-dev`

Comment: You have an extra "install" in your commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is Fedora-20, and I found this worked:

```
sudo yum install python-opengl
sudo yum install python-devel SDL_image-devel SDL_mixer-devel SDL_ttf-devel SDL-devel smpeg-devel numpy subversion portmidi-devel
```

Downloaded the smpeg from the website:

http://freecode.com/projects/smpeg

and did a local install:

```
sudo yum localinstall smpeg-0.4.5-2.1.x86_64.rpm 
sudo yum install pygame pygame-devel
```