# Pygame: Font module not available

Tags: python, fonts, module, pygame

### Running Python 2.7.2, and Pygame 1.9.2pre on OS X.

Another noobious issue: Initialising the pygame.font module produces an error that I dare not... well, attempt to solve myself. I'm guessing this is a rather generic pygame-related issue... but I haven't been able to find any solutions.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.font.init()
```

Gives:

```
Desktop/font.py:4: RuntimeWarning: use font: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found
(ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found)
  pygame.font.init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/font.py", line 4, in <module>
    pygame.font.init()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found)
```

---

What exactly is wrong here? What are some possible reasons that the font module could not be available? Common causes? Common fixes?

If anyone can enlighten me about what's wrong, I'll appreciate it even if it doesn't solve the problem!
Thanks very much!

***Edit:** I am using 64 bit version of Python with 32 bit Pygame. (There seems to be no 64 bit Pygame available for Mac OS)*

Comment: Why do you need to do `font.init`?

This method is called automatically by `pygame.init()`, so if it passes the `pygame.init()` line of code, you should be safe to use pygame fonts

Comment: Isn't this necessary before loading fonts from files? font = pygame.font.Font(none, 24) gives a similar error.

Comment: Try this and see what happends: `myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman" 30)` (with out the `pygame.font.init()`)

Comment: Hmm... maybe it is handled with in `pygame.init()`, but why does that not create an error when `font.init()` does?

Comment: I'm not sure. That is rather peculiar, but if fonts work with out the use of that statement then there is no need to worry about it.

Comment: I guess the problem lies with the fonts then... because they don't work either...

Comment: Did you try the line of code that I suggested in my second comment? What exactly happened when you did that?

Comment: Exactly the same error as above.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: OS X 10.8.4 Mountain Lion. Running Python 2.7.2, and Pygame 1.9.2pre. Doing anything that starts with `pygame.font.` raises the same error; the one mentioned above. Including `pygame.font.init` and `pygame.font.Font(etc)`.

Comment: Are you using 32bit py and 32bit pygame?

Comment: 64 bit Python, but I think Pygame is 32 bit... bother... could that be the problem? Pygame seems to work fine otherwise though...

Comment: If pygame seams to work fine otherwise, I would say it's probably not the problem. However, it defiantly can't hurt to try. You really should be using 64 bit pygame if you have a 64 bit architecture though.

Comment: According to [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.090/www/pygame.html), there is no 64 bit pygame for Mac, but I will try using both py's in 32.

Comment: No luck. Same errors as before... but I will be more careful about which architectures I use from now on, I wasn't previously aware of the clash.

Comment: UPDATE: It works! After _re_ installing Pygame 32 bit, (even though it was always in 32), it fixed itself. Everything is seamless. 32 vs 64; Lesson learned. :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(self answer)*

**Problem:** Using 32-bit Pygame with 64-bit Python generally isn't a good idea.

**Solution:** Always use Python and Pygame both in 64-bit architecture. (Or 32).

*P.S. Currently there doesn't seem to be a 64-bit Pygame for OS X, so you'll have to use a 32-bit Python.*

*P.S.S (After installing a 32-bit Python you may need to re-install the 32-bit Pygame for it to have any effect. This is what happened to me)*

Comment: On 64 bit ubuntu 16, install     
sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-0    and install pygame thru  conda install -c cogsci pygame

Answer (score 3):

I encounter the same problem, and the making-this-problem progress is as follow:

1. I download the `pygame` source file from the http://www.pygame.org/
2. I install the `pygame` with command `python setup.py install`

Then, I can `import pygame` and use basic pygame functions normally, but if I try to import other relative modules like `import pygame.font`, it jumps out `font module not found` error. I try to fix this problem by install some missing modules manually [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368766/1424948):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev  
libsdl-ttf2.0-dev   libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion 
libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev
```

However, this problem still exists.

At last, I realize this is a dependency problem, so I remove installed pygame by the command `sudo python setup.py clean` and remove all files in `python/site-packages`. I reinstall the `pygame` by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

and everything works fine.