# I Can't Install Pygame With Pip3 Due To Tons Of Missing Dependencies

Tags: python, linux, pygame, debian, failed-installation

I am trying to install pygame with pip3 on Debian GNU/Linux 9. However, once I enter the command `sudo pip3 install pygame` I get a bunch of missing dependencies:

`WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    Hunting dependencies...
    WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
    SDL     : found 1.2.15
    FONT    : not found
    IMAGE   : not found
    MIXER   : not found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : not found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    PORTTIME: not found
    FREETYPE: found 2.6.3
    Missing dependencies`

After this I used apt to install python-pygame, because I thought that contained all of the dependencies I needed. However, I still can't import pygame, and if I run pip3 install again, I get the same errors. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: any specific reason for using Debian 9 (aka stretch)? Debian 10 (aka buster) has been released 9 months ago? consider upgrading? did i mention that it comes with [python3-pygame](https://packages.debian.org/buster/python3-pygame)

Comment: @umläute I've tried the ways I know for upgrading, but when I did `cat /etc/issue`, that's what came up. Also, I'm doing this on a Chromebook, so that might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For debian, you can try usig apt-get to install.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
```

Also make sure you are importing the module using python3 and not python2.

Comment: Alas, this did not work. I got an error message saying `E: Package 'python3-pygame' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Seems like you have a similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652385/where-can-i-find-and-install-the-dependencies-for-pygame

Answer (score 0):

not certain of my answer, and with <50 rep, I am not allowed to comment, so I will take a shot at an answer, which may not be correct.  I believe that 'sudo pip3' is not the right way to install PyPI packages, since that will install them for root, and not for your user.  I think you want to use just 'pip3' (that is working for me).  If you need to use sudo, you might try 'sudo -H pip3', which should put them in the right place (if you need to use sudo - you should not need it for python3 package installs AFAIK)...

This helped me: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Hope that helps!

Comment: This also doesn't work. I end up getting the exact same error message anyway. Thanks for trying to answer my question anyway!

Answer (score -1):

For python 2 try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

For python 3 try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
```